# Cannot connect to local Database on fresh installed Windows 7 SP1

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-7-x64, local-database

I wrote a simple Windows Form Application and it works fine on my Computer with Visual Studio (2012):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=\localDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=5");
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("opened");
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("closed");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Now, I have a fresh installed Windows 7 SP1 Computer only with .Net 4.5 (without Visual Studio) to test my applications. When I start my Application.exe on this Computer it cannot establish an Connection to the local db.

Whats wrong? Do I have to install something? Missing References?

Comment: LocalDb requires an install - [SQL Server 2016 Express LocalDB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh510202.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, this worked!